# How to replace all HTML Tags in <head> wrapped into two html-comments using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags

In my HTML document's head is a section of tags (meta, link, ...) wrapped into two specific comments (specified by comments text-content). I want to take everything within those comments including the comments, delete it and then paste something else into it.

Example before:

```
    <head>
      <title>My Website</title>
      <meta property="test" content="some content" />
      ...
      <!-- This is the first comment -->
      <meta property="hi" content="something" />
      <link rel="canonical" href="http://website.com/test/">
      <!-- This is the second comment -->
      ...
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//use.typekit.net">
    </head>
```

Example after:

```
    <head>
      <title>My Website</title>
      <meta property="test" content="some content" />
      ...
      <!-- This is the first NEW comment -->
      <meta property="hi" content="something new" />
      <link rel="canonical" href="http://website.com/hi-im-new/">
      <meta property="hiagain" content="something completely new" />
      <!-- This is the second NEW comment -->
      ...
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//use.typekit.net">
    </head>
```

Comment: please share some context of the issue - what did you try so far? what do you mean by replacing x.html to y.html? is it a static file that you simply want to swap its' content?

Comment: DOM parser etc doesn't maintain comments, so your need to use regex or simple replace, Q: how will you match some arbitrary string/comment `<!-- This is the first comment -->` to switch it with something new, do you have a list of replacements or are you simply looking to add NEW in between first and comment?

Comment: Do you run this code in the browser? Or do you want to serve a file in nodejs?

Comment: you can read and write to the element by using document.head.innerHTML attribute. maybe do a custom string manipulation using that and replace the innerHTML at that time.